# Android-studio Project fails to run

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio

I'm currently working on a project in android studio and as a part of my project I needed to clean it. I followed the proper steps and now my assignment wont load.

I keep getting these errors and I don't know what they mean. Please help!

[image]

Comment: You can try removing android:layout_centerCrop and see if it side steps the build error. I couldn't find the location of layout_centerCrop with my brief google search. Is it a custom layout or you might be missing SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error basically says that the layout attribute mentioned is not identified, or is nonexistent. In this case, it is `layout_centerCrop`. Please replace `android:layout_centerCrop="true"` with `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

By the way, I would suggest `centerInside` rather than `centerCrop` so that none if the image will be cropped out, and will still be in the same aspect ratio.
It will look like this:

```
<ImageView
android:src="@drawable/sundae"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your ImageView definition to:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/sundae"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

I don't believe the tag "layout_centerCrop" exists.